# Ant failing with Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: ant, build, subant

I am using subant and it is resulting into *Content is not allowed in prolog* problem.

```
    <subant target="main" genericantfile="build.xml">
        <fileset dir = "." />
    </subant>
```

Error:

```
The following error occurred while executing this line:
pattern.py:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

Please note I have different files in those folders for example, python files.

When I use explicit listing using the filelist, all works fine.

```
<subant target="main" genericantfile="build.xml">                
      <filelist dir="." 
           files = "A/build.xml,
                    B/build.xml"
   />
</subant>
```

Comment: "Content is not allowed in prolog" normally indicates a problem parsing files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With subant you *either* specify `genericantfile` along with a `dirset` (to run the same build file many times, each time with a different basedir) *or* you omit `genericantfile` but supply a `fileset` or other resource collection of build files to run.  You are mixing the two styles, and it looks like when you provide a `fileset` ant is ignoring the `genericantfile` attribute and treating each element of that fileset as a build file, attempting to parse each of the files as XML, and failing for those that are not XML (i.e. the python files).

```
<subant target="main">
    <fileset dir = "." includes="**/build.xml" />
</subant>
```

would include only the real build files in the fileset.